# Container_scanning FATAL scan error / unable to initialize a scanner

Tags: docker, gitlab, scanning, trivy

gitlab `container_scanning` fails with thoses 4 errors on `docker deamon`, `initialize Podman client`, `containerd deamon` and `repository authentication`.
Thais is the log:

```
....
trivy image --vuln-type os --no-progress --offline-scan --skip-update --security-checks vuln --format template --template @/usr/local/bundle/gems/gcs-5.2.7/lib/template/trivy.tpl --output tmp.json registry.gitlab.com/xxxx/temp:1442 00:04
[DEBUG] [2023-02-22 16:39:59 +0000] [container-scanning]  >  trivy image --vuln-type os --no-progress --offline-scan --skip-update --security-checks vuln --format template --template @/usr/local/bundle/gems/gcs-5.2.7/lib/template/trivy.tpl --output tmp.json registry.gitlab.com/xxxx/temp:1442
[DEBUG] [2023-02-22 16:40:03 +0000] [container-scanning]  >  2023-02-22T16:39:59.813Z   DEBUG   Severities: ["UNKNOWN" "LOW" "MEDIUM" "HIGH" "CRITICAL"]
2023-02-22T16:39:59.820Z    DEBUG   cache dir:  /home/gitlab/.cache/trivy/ce
2023-02-22T16:39:59.820Z    DEBUG   Skipping DB update...
2023-02-22T16:39:59.820Z    DEBUG   DB Schema: 2, UpdatedAt: 2023-02-21 12:07:46.494248011 +0000 UTC, NextUpdate: 2023-02-21 18:07:46.494247711 +0000 UTC, DownloadedAt: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2023-02-22T16:40:02.898Z    INFO    Vulnerability scanning is enabled
2023-02-22T16:40:02.898Z    DEBUG   Vulnerability type:  [os]
2023-02-22T16:40:03.337Z    FATAL   image scan error:
    github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact.Run
        /home/runner/work/trivy/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact/run.go:397
  - scan error:
    github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact.(*runner).scanArtifact
        /home/runner/work/trivy/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact/run.go:257
  - unable to initialize a scanner:
    github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact.scan
        /home/runner/work/trivy/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact/run.go:582
  - unable to initialize a docker scanner:
    github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact.imageStandaloneScanner
        /home/runner/work/trivy/trivy/pkg/commands/artifact/scanner.go:22
  - 4 errors occurred:
    * unable to inspect the image (registry.gitlab.com/xxxx/temp:1442): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
    * unable to initialize Podman client: no podman socket found: stat podman/podman.sock: no such file or directory
    * containerd socket not found: /run/containerd/containerd.sock
    * GET https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/xxxx/temp/manifests/1442: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:xxxx/temp Type:repository]]
[DEBUG] [2023-02-22 16:40:03 +0000] [container-scanning]  >  
[INFO] [2023-02-22 16:40:03 +0000] [container-scanning]  >  Scan failed. Use `SECURE_LOG_LEVEL=debug` to see more details.
[ERROR] [2023-02-22 16:40:03 +0000] [container-scanning]  >  The credentials set in CS_REGISTRY_USER and CS_REGISTRY_PASSWORD are either empty or not valid. Please set valid credentials.
....
```

```
include:
  - template: Jobs/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - Build Image
  - test

Build_Docker:
  tags:
    - xxxx-runner
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:18-dind
  stage: Build Image
  variables:
    APP_NAME: xxxx/temp
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
  script:
    - docker build -f xxxx/Dockerfile -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID .
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_script, rules]

container_scanning:
  image: "$CS_ANALYZER_IMAGE$CS_IMAGE_SUFFIX"
  stage: test
  needs: ["Build_Docker"]
  variables:
    APP_NAME: xxxx/temp
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: 'debug'
    CI_GITLAB_FIPS_MODE: "false"
    CS_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
    CS_REGISTRY_USER: "xxxx"
    CS_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: "$xxxxx"
```

I tried adding those variables but still facing same error.

```
CS_REGISTRY_USER: "xxxx" 
CS_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: "$xxxxx"
```

I also tried this but facing same error

```
container_scanning:
  extends: .job_aws 
  stage: test
  needs: ["Build_Docker"]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    TRIVY_USERNAME: "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    TRIVY_PASSWORD: "$TrivyPassword"
    TRIVY_AUTH_URL: "$CI_REGISTRY"
    FULL_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''
  before_script:
    - !reference [.before_script.docker, before_script]
    - yum install -y gettext
    - yum install -y tar gzip
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aquasecurity/trivy/main/contrib/install.sh | sh -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
    - trivy --version
    - time trivy image --clear-cache
    - time trivy image --download-db-only --no-progress --cache-dir .trivycache/
    # Builds report and puts it in the default workdir $CI_PROJECT_DIR, so `artifacts:` can take it from there
    - time trivy image --exit-code 0 --debug --cache-dir .trivycache/ --no-progress --format template --template "@/contrib/gitlab.tpl"
        --output "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/gl-container-scanning-report.json" "$FULL_IMAGE_NAME"
    # - time trivy image --exit-code 0 --debug --cache-dir .trivycache/ --no-progress --output "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/gl-container-scanning-report.json" "$FULL_IMAGE_NAME"
    # # Fail on critical vulnerabilities
    # - time trivy image --exit-code 1 --debug --cache-dir .trivycache/ --no-progress --severity CRITICAL  "$FULL_IMAGE_NAME"
  cache:
    paths:
      - .trivycache/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      container_scanning: gl-container-scanning-report.json
```

Thanks for any help?

Comment: What is the type of runner executor?